# how to get nearest point to a given point in points of polygon?

Tags: wpf

Here is image ,

[image: Img]

I want to know how to get nearest point to a given point [can be anywhere] [green one] , for array of points. By seeing we can get, but how to do same in code ?

Comment: plz don't mind points in img, only for explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the distance to each point:

```
distance = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

Then take the min of that. There are probably more efficient ways of doing it (e.g. octtrees) for very large # of points.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between between two points can be found by using the [distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance). By implementing this formula, you can iterate through your collection of points and find the closest one to your starting point.